# Firebase: local functions emulator throws a 401 Unauthenticated

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I've set up the emulators in my project and all of them work fine, except for functions where I receive a 401 Unauthenticated errors.

Is there some other setting somewhere for functions I need to consider when using locally?

My app setup code including functions used to make requests:

```js
import { initializeApp, getApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getFunctions, httpsCallable, connectFunctionsEmulator } from 'firebase/functions'

export const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MEASUREMENT_ID
}

function createFirebaseApp(firebaseConfig) {
  try {
    return getApp()
  } catch {
    return initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
  }
}
const functions = getFunctions(firebaseApp)

export const createCustomer = httpsCallable(functions, 'createCustomer')
```

emulator config in `firebase.json`:

```json
"emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "port": 9099
    },
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001
    },
    "firestore": {
      "port": 8080
    },
    "database": {
      "port": 9000
    },
    "hosting": {
      "port": 5002
    },
    "storage": {
      "port": 9199
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "singleProjectMode": true
  },
```

I set up all emulators the same based off the docs:

```js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  connectAuthEmulator(auth, 'http://127.0.0.1:9099')
  connectFunctionsEmulator(functions, '127.0.0.1', 5001)
  connectFirestoreEmulator(db, '127.0.0.1', 8080)
  connectStorageEmulator(storage, '127.0.0.1', 9199)
}
```

In the browser it tells me its attempting to hit the local function:

`http://127.0.0.1:5001/my-project-dev/us-central1/createCustomer 401 (Unauthorized)`

This is the output of the logs but I cant see any auth errors:

```json
20:18:23 Beginning execution of "us-central1-createCustomer"
{
  "key": "x-callable-context-auth",
  "value": " -- removed for privacy -- ",
  "severity": "DEBUG",
  "message": "Callable functions auth override"
}
20:18:23 function[us-central1-createCustomer]
{
  "verifications": {
    "app": "MISSING",
    "auth": "VALID"
  },
  "logging.googleapis.com/labels": {
    "firebase-log-type": "callable-request-verification"
  },
  "severity": "DEBUG",
  "message": "Callable request verification passed"
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to share enough information that anyone can use to reproduce the issue.  We can't see how you've set up and configured the emulator that's supposed to receive and handle the request, nor can we see the code that makes the request.  We should have all of that in order to reproduce it.

Comment: thanks @DougStevenson, I updated with further details

Comment: Where is `createCustomer`?  We need all the relevant code that's part of the invocation.  You've showed that it logs some things, but we can't see what it might do to issue an unexpected response.  Ideally you can provide a complete minimal implementation of a function that fails in this way.

Comment: And to be clear - your client is invoking it from the global scope of some web page, which happens immediately on page load?  That doesn't seem right.

Comment: I'm just trying to consolidate it down, everything works in prod envvironments. `createCustomer` lives in the `functions` folder of a firebase experimental features NextJS project.  But in terms of emulators setup, is there any code or config missing?

Comment: I don't know.  What's missing for me is the code that gets executed.  The emulator is only a rough approximation of the actual service.  You might be doing something problematic for it, but I can't tell.  Please provide a complete minimal implementation of a function that fails in this way when run in the emulator.  Also I'll ask again: is your client is invoking it from the global scope of some web page, which happens immediately on page load?

Comment: No the function does not get called on page load, but the firebase app initialises then, and then I trigger the connectEmulator methods.  I'll try to replicate it in a new project tomorrow. Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

As @Doug Stevenson pointed out, I forgot about the function triggers, (I totally forgot the file even existed, sorry Doug). Of course I had to turn off AppCheck in development. This works but maybe theres a better way to configure AppCheck..

```js
const isProductionEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
exports.createCustomer = functions
  .runWith({
    enforceAppCheck: isProductionEnv,
    secrets: ['STRIPE_SECRET_API_KEY']
  })
  .https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    return await createCustomer(data)
  })
```